# c# textbox zero validation

Tags: c#, if-statement

I've been facing a very basic issue, I want to validate textbox not equals to zero( != "0" ) validation. But even though the textbox is zero the if condition I used to validate becomes true and allows.

```cs
textbox.text = "0";
if(textbox.text != "0")
{
//textbox value is zero but, if statement becomes true somehow and execute the code inside the if statement that shouldn't be happen right?. I need to know why.
}
```

But if I validate for equals to zero( == "0" ) works

```
if(textbox.text == "0")
{
//do something
}
else
{
//now the condition worked and comes to else part.
}
```

This also happens for validating null or empty, I know we can user string.IsnullorEmpty to validate string or null. But I want to know why even though the textbox value is null or empty or zero the if statement for not equals isn't working.

Comment: Do you have `ValueChanged` or similar event handler which can probably change the value before executing `if .. else`?

Comment: yes the textbox has a  TextChanged event, will this affect the if statement?

Comment: Remove it and see if it has an effect ;)

Comment: The fact of having an event handler will not affect an if statement. But the handler code may be changing the text - we cannot tell

Comment: @Fabio I checked the if statement after removing the textChagned event, but it does the same thing allows  the false statement.

Comment: @krickx, c# is not broken if value is `"0"` then if statement `if (value != "0")` will never be true. There something going on after assignment `textbox.Text = "0"`. Try it with different values, debug and see how value of `.Text` property changes before `if` statements. Check again that there are no other events which can change value. Alternative approach - create new TextBox and see if you can reproduce similar behaviour with totally new control.

Comment: Use the debugger to check the value of that Text property. Maybe it contains extra spaces?

Comment: @Fabio I've debugged many times the statement becomes true, its surprises me. Its not only with zero, this case also happening with null and empty validations.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I also checked with trim() and debugged.

Comment: This question needs a [mre]. As you see it is almost impossible to tell whats going on from the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

"the textbox is zero"
You need to learn the difference between = and ==.

`textbox.text == "0"` checks if the value of the .text property is zero and returns **true** or **false**

`textbox.text = 0` sets the value of the .text property to zero

Instead of:

```
    textbox.text=="0";
    if(textbox.text!="0")
    {
    //do something.
    }
```

Do:

```
    textbox.text="0";
    if(textbox.text!="0")
    {
    //do something.
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while typing. I've corrected now.